# Remote MongoDB successful only when MongoDB is open on local

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a Ubuntu VM in an EC2 AWS instance, with MongoDB installed. I can successfully save information to this database on my local machine using a spring boot application. However, this remote connection can only be made when I have a connection to remote Mongodb open on my local machine. Otherwise, the connection is refused.

My end goal is to have a mobile application that can preform CURD operations to a remote MongoDB.

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what version of mongodb it is?

Comment: Both versions are 3.6.2

Comment: You optionally host your app in same or another ec2 instance from where this mongodb instance is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to connect to a remote MongoDB from a mobile application because anyone will be able to tamper with the information you are storing in it.

Consider using a local database bundled along with your mobile application or connecting from your mobile application to your Spring boot app which can then talk to the MongoDB instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To clarify: Should I have 2 applications? First Mobile App, 2nd Spring Boot app, then spring boot app be stored in EC2 instance alongside MongoDB?

Comment: It depends. Any reason why you don't want to bundle the database with your mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

Please check some point.

1: Please check remote connection open in your Mongo instance

2: Ec2 Instance have public accessibility

3: Ec2 Instance mongo port enabled and remotely accessible.

Did you confirm that the bind_ip actually changed to 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0